# How to create a search index with CURL or HTTP API in CouchDB?

Tags: curl, lucene, couchdb, cloudant

How to create similar design to this one:

```
{
   "_id": "_design/foo",
   "_rev": "1-166900c56b2e87d91bb48dcf890c84ed",
   "fulltext": {
       "by_title": {
           "index": "function(doc) { var ret=new Document(); ret.add(doc.title); return ret }"
       }
   }
}
```

taken from this tutorial:
[BlogPost](http://blog.tryolabs.com/2011/02/23/django-couchdb-and-lucene-integration/)

I have recompiled my CouchDB to allow couchdb-lucene.
[github couchdb-lucene](http://github.com/rnewson/couchdb-lucene)

The problem I have is that I couldn't find any appropriate example to try to insert the design without the UI, which allows only design views, not search indexes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Design documents can be created the same way as regular documents, so you could use the [HTTP API for documents](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/api/document/common.html).

You could save the design in a file, say 'yourdesign.json', and upload it with such a command:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X PUT http://127.0.0.1:5984/yourdb/_design/foo -d @yourdesign.json
```